# Errors with long integer in Python 3

Tags: python, int, significant-digits

I have this program that changes a number into words, but the problem is that when you have more than 16 digits in the number, it starts changing the numbers. This is done in Python 3 and we are wondering why this is happening and if there is a simple workaround? (We suspect that Python only handles 16 significant digits)  Of course it could be a silly bug and in which case, I apologise... But we've had 3 sets of eyes on this and can't spot anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
digit1 = ["","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
digit2 = ["","twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"]
other = ["","thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion","nonillion","decillion","undecillion","duodecillion","tredecillion","quattuordecillion","quindecillion","sexdecillion","septendecillion","octodecillion","novemdecillion","vigintillion","centillion"]
teens = ["","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","eighteen","nineteen"]
text = ""


number = input("Enter number: ")
try:
    number = float(number)
except ValueError:
    print ("That's not a number")
    exit()
decimal = number
number = int(number)


def Num2Text(num):
    out = ""
    if len(num) >= 3:
        out += digit1[int(num[0])] + " hundred "
    if len(num) >= 2 and num[-2] != "1":
        out += digit2[int(num[-2])-1] + " "
    if len(num) >= 1 and num[-2] != "1":
        out += digit1[int(num[-1])] + " "
    if num[-2] == "1":
        out += teens[int(num[-1])] + " "
    return out


number = str(number)
cycles = len(number)/3
cycles = round(cycles+0.49)

for i in range(cycles,0,-1):
    cnumber = str(int(decimal/1000**(i-1)))
    cnumber = cnumber[-3:]
    text += Num2Text(cnumber)
    text += other[i-1]  + " "


print(text)
```

Comment: don't use float, use int. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

Comment: Python floats only have (approximately) 15 significant digits (53 bits). But int can be as big as you like (assuming you have enough RAM).

Comment: Inputting `1` throws an exception, inputting `10` outputs nothing, and inputting `105` outputs "one hundred ninety five". Are you really sure the length of the number is the problem...?

Comment: BTW, there's a popular 3rd-party module `num2words` that's pretty good.

Comment: @Ignacio That's a great link, but it's not a good match for this particular question, IMHO.

Comment: @PM2Ring: It's not an exact match, but it does explain the underlying problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry, but how is this question related to floats? As far as I can tell, we're dealing with integers here.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: The calculations for `cycles` and `cnumber`.